# Why is my Viewpager not showing any fragments after opening the second time and why can childfragmentmanager not be used?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager

I have a Fragment (InnerFragment) placed inside a Viewpager (MainViewPager).

This Fragment (InnerFragment) does also contain a ViewPager (NestedViewPager) with multiple Fragments. When I swipe or open the InnerFragment everything works fine and the NestedViewPager shows all Fragments the way it should.

When I leave the InnerFragment after swiping the MainViewPager and go back to the InnerFragment it is blank and **nothing shows up**.

One solution as described in the internet is **using the childfragmentmanager**. Unfortunately this doesn't work because if I do so **following exception is thrown**.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment ProductImageFragment{c458f99 (1213d869-3715-4541-8nab-f87cyc350630) id=0x8f093165 android:switcher:2111xxxxxx:0} declared target fragment ProductImagesFragment{4b4f25e (99a6aaf6-5500-4821-902f-7bf30f87554c) id=0x7f090126 android:switcher:2131296550:2} that does not belong to this FragmentManager!
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:805)
```

Maybe it is also important to note, that the **MainFragment is implementing an Interface of the Innerfragment**.

**MainFragment**

```
class ProductImagesFragment : Fragment(),
    ProductImageFragment.IProductImageHandler,
    ProductImageUploadDialog.ProductImageUploadDialogEventListener {

    private lateinit var viewPager: ViewPager

    interface IProductImageUploadHandler{
        fun onImageUploadToServerFinished(bitmap: Bitmap, imageData: ProductImage)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }
   

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View?
    {
        return layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product_images,container,false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.viewPagerImages)
        setViewPagerAdapter()
    }

    private fun setViewPagerAdapter(){
        val manager = fragmentManager
        if(manager!=null){
            viewPager.adapter = product?.let {product ->
                ImageAdapter(this,
                    product,productImageList,manager)
            }
        }
    }

class ImageAdapter(private val productImagesFragment: ProductImagesFragment, private val product: Product, private val imagesList:ArrayList<ProductImage>, fragmentManager: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fragmentManager) {

        override fun getCount(): Int {
            return imagesList.size
        }

        override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
            val fragment = ProductImageFragment()
            val bundle = Bundle()
            val image = imagesList[position]
            bundle.putInt("productId",product.id)
            bundle.putParcelable("productImage",image)
            bundle.putInt("maxImages",imagesList.size)
            fragment.setTargetFragment(productImagesFragment,1)
            fragment.arguments = bundle
            return fragment
        }
    }


}
```

**InnerFragment**

```
class ProductImageFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var productImageHandler: IProductImageHandler

    interface IProductImageHandler{
        fun onImageDeleted(id: Int)
        fun onOrderChanged(url: String, newValue: Int, oldValue: Int)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        try {
            productImageHandler = targetFragment as IProductImageHandler
        }catch (exception: Exception){
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product_image, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       
    }

    private fun setValues(view: View){
        
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of using `fragmentManager` .. try using use `requireActivity().supportFragmentManager`

Comment: @Zain no that is wrong.

Comment: **Fragment ProductImageFragment declared target fragment ProductImagesFragment that does not belong to this FragmentManager!** <-- error message

Comment: Hey @EpicPandaForce  thanks man.. I believe they should use `childFragmentManger` but as OP got `IllegalStateException` that `supportFragmentManager` can be rescuer instead of the deprecated `fragmentManager`

Comment: No, it will just break on forward then back navigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **must** use the `childFragmentManager` in order for the state to be restored properly.

You shouldn't be using the target fragment API at all. In fact, if you're using the `childFragmentManager`, your child fragments already have a reference to the parent via `requireParentFragment()` - just use that instead of `targetFragment`.

```
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    try {
         productImageHandler = requireParentFragment() as IProductImageHandler
    }catch (exception: Exception){
    }
}
```